# Shell script to extract strings between xml tags

Tags: xml, string, shell, extract

Can you please help me to extract strings between xml tags.
xml input:

```
    <Name ns1:translate="yes">Overview</Name>
    <Title ns1:translate="yes">This is a book</Title>
    <Description ns1:translate="yes"/>
    <TextValue ns1:translate="yes">End</TextValue>
```

Expected output:

```
    Overview = Overview
    This is a book = This is a book
       =
    End = End
```

Comment: If you'll have to do more work with XML then you might want to use/learn [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and [XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_example.asp).

Answer (score 3):

If you want just remove tags, you can do it this way:

```
$ sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

If you want to repeat the text in tags, you need something like:

```
$ sed 's/.*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1 = \1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion:
Please use PERL for XML read/extraction. PERL has many modules XML parsing modules [both SAX/DOM].

OR even Python is perfect choice for XML parsing.